# Dual-boot Linux and PrimeOS, no options in Grub

Tags: linux, partition, dual-boot, grub, zorin

my old laptop is weak with Windows and I wanted to install some lightweight OS but encountered a problem when wanted two of them.

I have Linux partitioned like this - /dev/sda:

- /boot - primary (Grub partition?)
- /home - logical
- / - logical
  (root)
- /var - logical
- swap - logical
- and this one with no mount
  point - primary (ext4), which I left for Prime OS installation.

When I finished with Linux installation, I tried to install Prime OS with and without its Grub, but I never see it on boot. My laptop goes directly to Linux without the boot menu. When it boots, I can see a 200GB Partition on my desktop with Prime OS files inside.

How can I make a custom entry in Grub Customizer if my target partition is /dev/sda3? Is it (hd0,3) and how to write a custom boot sequence?

Or, what else I can do?
Does `sudo update-grub` make life easier?

Comment: Most desktop users do not need /boot nor /var partitions, some with servers may. Nor can you share those at all. You should not share /home, but use a data partition for most of the data in /home. Then changing user configuration in one system will not modify the other or create conflicts. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: There is a pastebin link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3BmhvgwQRn/
I made /boot because I was thinking it would be a Grub partition. I'm noob at Linux based systems.

Comment: You said older, but looks like newer UEFI system. Often better to then install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive, not old BIOS/MBR configuration. Your sda3 is only showing a grub legacy's menu.lst and not the rest of any install. Grub2 has been the standard for about 10 years, only a very few systems may still use grub legacy. Do not run any fixes with Boot-Repair as it does not automatically mount /var. Not sure if manually mounting then works. You have to manually reinstall grub with chroot, if needed. Chroot,  Best to use same version https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Comment: I have no option in my BIOS to set UEFI instead of legacy. Can I do the job with Chroot even if my sda3 partition is not showing the installed system? Also, I wonder if I can format the disk, install PrimeOS first, then install my Linux (Ubuntu) based system Zorin OS? I don't prefer that, because I already set-up my Zorin OS.

Comment: Your Zorin is in sda6, so should be able to chroot into it and reinstall grub.  Does not look like any install in sda3, just old grub? Typically better not to have partitions for /boot nor /var with most desktop installs. Some with servers may need or want those as separate partitions.  both become more partitions to manage size of and may have space you want in other partitions.